# Extract Rectangle Containing Number from an Image

Tags: image, matlab, template-matching

I am trying to make a program to read the numbers of container serial number using template matching, based on this http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40426-vehicle-number-plate-recognition.

My biggest problem is to extract the single *check number* of the serial number. The check number is the 11th number of the set, as you can see in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKuPy.png), the number is 6, contained in a rectangle. After some pre-processings, the the rectangle totally filled because of floodfill.

My idea is to take that 11th number and process it separately, and to do that, I have to detect the rectangle and extract it from the image. But I can't find a good way to do that. Can someone help me with this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your explanation is clear, but you should also share what you have done so far.

Comment: read about matrix indexing in MATLAB